# alloy appcelerator textfield font color not visible in android version 5

Tags: colors, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

alloy accelerator textfield text font color is not visible.I have tried to change background color and color of the textfield but it still showing that error.

Answer (score 0):

In tiapp.xml add custom theme.
You can refer [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Android_Themes)

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"> </style>
</resources>
```